# How do I add a column with "KEY" index not "primary key" in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to add Index KEY to a column in SQLite. I am talking about "Index type: INDEX" not primary key. Please suggest me some statement for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)
```